# Understanding time constant of high-pass filter at op-amp input

Tags: operational-amplifier, active-filter

In the circuit attached, R17 is the load resistor for a CT which measures 50/60 Hz currents. The switch is a CMOS analog one, not electromechanical.

When the switch is closed, the gain is about R16/R14 = 49.9k/832 = 60. When the switch is open, the gain is R16/(R14+R15) = 49.9k/(832+49k) = 1.

The cutoff frequency of the low pass filter is 1/(2π·R16·C17) = 678 Hz

My question is about the AC coupling cap which forms a high-pass filter.

When the switch is closed, the cutoff frequency is 1/(2π·R14·C18) = 4 Hz and time constant RC = 39 ms.
When the switch is open, the cutoff frequency is 1/(2π·(R14+R15)·C18) = 0.068 Hz and time constant RC = 2.34 s

Is there a negative effect of these time constants on my 60 Hz signal (16.67 ms period)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should analyze in the frequency domain, forget the time constants.

When the switch is closed, you expect a gain of 60, but it is about 1% less because you are not far enough from the cutoff. You will need to decide if this is OK. [Edit: component tolerances will make the error larger]

The current transformer can't have DC on it, so C18 isn't really necessary. Worse, you have it shown as a non-polarized and that is awfully large for a non-polarized cap. And it should be non-polarized. It won't go negative very much, so it might work, but this isn't recommended.

I used the CircuitLab simulator. I can solve this, but I am not in the mood to do the math right now.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxSklJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Note that the frequency sweep will default to a voltage of 1, so the voltage is unrealistic, but it is an indication of the gain.

Comment: Thanks. I was worried if the time constants caused some delay in my signal or other unwanted effect. I could adjust the resistors to improve the cutoff frequency or to use a smaller capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what your error tolerance is, or what kind of accuracy or precision you need.  With 1% tolerance resistors, your output accuracy is limited to less than 7 bits of resolution.  So the question is, in the 4 Hz condition, does the rolloff error (caused my non-flatness of the response curve) at almost four octaves above the cutoff frequency contribute more than or less than 1% to the output.  IOW, is it a significant error source.

Calculate the capacitor impedance at 60 Hz, use that to calculate the R-C network signal attenuation in percent, and convert that to dB if needed.  For the real world, do the calculations for the worst case values at the extremes of the resistor and capacitor tolerances.